# GraphStream drawing grouped nodes in graph

Tags: java, layout, graph, graphstream

I already created graph with different color each graph based on some attribute in its node. This is my current graph
[image: graph]

Is it possible to place node that has same color closely? How could I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for a similar functionality and came across Viewers (http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Graph-Visualisation_1.0/). I disabled the default viewer and mentioned co-ordinates for individual nodes (which works but doesn't look pretty and is additional headache to mention co-ordinates in the code).

However, I haven't figured out if we can still use default viewer and group nodes based on some attributes.

Let me know if you figure out a way to do that.

Comment: It solved, just try to set position attribute on each node by x coordinates using node.setAttribute('x', value). This is mine, here http://pasteboard.co/LKcD5iZ.png